# Preventing ex commands from altering the screen

Tags: command-line

Sometimes ex commands have the useless side effect of jumping, probably to the last place they affected. Can this be prevented? I would prefer it if ex commands left my screen exactly the same as before their execution.

Comment: Would [`:h :keepjumps`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#:keepjumps) be what you are looking for?

Comment: @statox, no, the screen still changes. keepj. seems to preserve some marks and lists, not the screen.

Comment: Arf I read your question too fast, sorry :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I don't see in the doc any option/flag you can use for a ex command, I think you can simply use the `C-o` command afterward.

From the documentation:

```
CTRL-O          Go to [count] Older cursor position in jump list
                (not a motion command).  {not in Vi}
                {not available without the |+jumplist| feature}
```

When you do a ex command, you can go back to the previous position with `C-o`. In my mind it does make sens to go to the last change resulting of the ex command, so that you can see if the change (i.e. in a substitution) had the desired effect.

If you do want to have a transparent call, you can use a custom command that take your ex command as an argument and restore the window automatically:

```
function! KeepEx(arg)
  let l:winview = winsaveview()
  execute a:arg
  call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction

command! -nargs=+ -completion=command K :call KeepEx("<args>")
```

You can use it like so:

```
:K %s/a/b/g
```

The `winsaveview` will fetch every info you need for restoring the view, so you get back to your previous state.

**Note**: if you delete line above your cursor it might be possible that you cannot restore fully your window, but that's an edge case.

Comment: c-o will take you back to the last cursor position, not the last screen state

Comment: you are right, let me update my answer (if I find out how ;) )

Comment: answer updated.

Comment: nice, thanks! do you think there is a way to do this always, without calling a special command?

Comment: I don't think so, as said in my answer, I haven't found any option while looking at the documentation for the ex command. But if one exists, I would be happy to know :)

Comment: Maybe you could use an autocommand? Maybe with WinEnter/WinLeave you could do something... Or how about remapping `:` to first save the view, then start the command window with a `:` in it and then restore the view on WinEnter?

Comment: remapping `:` seems risky IMHO, I wouldn't have to handle every when you actually want to ove cases (like `:tabnew`) I'd rather stay with a concrete proof that I want to keep my position

Comment: You're right, remapping wasn't a good idea.

Comment: If there are few ex commands that are used frequently, then it might be easier to create aliases for them, e.g.: `:%S/a/b/g`, `:G/a/d`, `:V/a/d`.

Comment: It might be worthwile to add completion to the comand, like
`command! -nargs=+ -completion=command K :call KeepEx("<args>")`

Comment: @nobe4 this does not work for me. I get an error `E181: Invalid attribute: completion=command `

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, I think I found a pretty good solution. You could use these to mappings to achieve the desired result:

```
noremap  <space>: m`:
cnoremap <c-j> <cr>``
```

Or if you want to simply replace the normal functionality:

```
noremap  : m`:
cnoremap <cr> <cr>``
```

These mapping will allow you to do something like `:%s/  /    /` for an entire file without moving the screen or cursor at all.