# How to restore cursor position after search and replace in autocmd

Tags: regular-expression, autocmd, cursor

I'd like to delete all spaces on empty lines before saving files. I've figured out how to do that.

```
autocmd BufWritePre * silent! %s/\v^\s+$//e
```

But this moves my cursor to the line where the spaces have been removed. I know that not in autocmd I can just press `''` and that would do what I want, but I can't figure out how to achieve this in autocmd.

Answer (score 4):

You could achieve `''` on an autocmd using the following:

```
:call setpos('.', getpos("''"))
```

Check [`:help function-list`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#function-list) for built-in functionality on VimL.

---

**Edit**

> okay, how to combine it with search and replace? Another autocmd after
>   the search and replace one?

Vim documentation is very comprehensive and well-written, you should definitively try reading it.

If you are going to write autocmds then [`:help cmd-lines`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/cmdline.txt.html#cmdline-lines) is a must read:

```
autocmd BufWritePre * %s/\v^\s+$//e | call setpos('.', getpos("''"))
```

You should also consider using autocmd groups, as explained in [`:help autocmd-groups`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#autocmd-groups).

Comment: okay, how to combine it with search and replace? Another autocmd after the search and replace one?

Comment: thanks!. You might want to fix typo the**n** :help cmd-lines

Comment: Okay, this isn't actually working. Somehow when I save file the cursor goes to the start of the file (even when I'm pressing ```''``` manually). However when I'm pressing manually backtick twice the cursor moves to the correct position (where it was before saving file). But! Somehow if I would change double single quote to double backtick in ```call setpos('.', getpos("``"))``` when I save file cursor still goes to the start of the file.

Comment: IMHO It works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired from [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/7241/3343) on another post, a possible solution would be

```
autocmd! BufWritePre * call KeepEx('silent! %s/\v^\s+$//e')

function! KeepEx(arg)
  let l:winview = winsaveview()
  execute a:arg
  call winrestview(l:winview)
endfunction
```

using the function `KeepEx` which can execute arbitrary functions and afterwards restore the old view.